# Firefox extension: write cookie names for the current web-page in a local .txt file

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox extension which should get all cookie names from the current visited web-page and write the names in a text file. So far I have the following code in javascript:

```
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var widget = widgets.Widget({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Main Menu",
  contentURL: require("sdk/self").data.url("icon-16.png"),
  onClick: function() {
    const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");
    var f = '/home/user4/Desktop/my-addon/exported.txt';
    var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(f);
    if(file.exists() == false) //check to see if file exists
    {
        file.create( Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 420);
    }
    var foStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
    foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0666, 0); 
    var converter = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIConverterOutputStream);
    converter.init(foStream,"UTF-8", 0, 0);
    converter.writeString('Some test string.');
    converter.close(); // this closes foStream
  }
});
```

which successfully creates the `exported.txt` file and writes the `"Some test string."` string in it. However, when I try

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

to get the cookies and then

```
converter.writeString(x);
```

to write the names in the text file, nothing happens. The extension does not even create en empty `.txt` file in this case.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whatst he value of `document.cookie` it should be string. If its empty nothing will write. I also advise that you use `OS.File` and `writeAtomic` see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread

Comment: @Noitidart Thank you for your advise. I have tried `writeAtomic` as well but I think I will use the `nsICookieService` as mentioned @nmaier. It seems the best solution for me.

Comment: `nsICookieService` won't write to file though. After using that cookie service you still have to decide how to write it to file, either using your method above (in topic post) or the reocmmended way by moz devs to use OS.File. But your choice, just sharing that its not just my rec.

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks for the good point. It will save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `document` and therefore no `document.cookie` in `main.js`.

- Either attach a content script via [`tabs.activeTab.attach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach%28options%29) or a similar `page-mod` and [communicate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on) the `document.cookie` value back from that content script to your `main.js` to write it to a file.
- Or use the [`nsICookieService`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieService) directly in some way.